# Manifolds with varying (local or global) dimension

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, complex-manifolds

What subject should one look into to understand manifolds with varying dimensions throughout it's structure.

For example, Imagine a 2-sphere with a line going through it defining some type of manifold, could we still consider that as a manifold? Or is it another type of geometric object.(non-'Pure' Mani,,,?<--I need something better than this).

Anyone who has any resources on differential geometries with non-constant dimensions please leave as an answer (I have university resources so feel free to offer 'subscription based' services).

Comment: look at the theory of foliations..

Comment: What do you want to do with these things? That really matters for the answers you want. If you want to do topology you can look at CW structures or simplicial complexes: but these are not smooth things (it is hard to do geometry/ analysis with them). There are also varying notions of stratified spaces: They can capture singularities that "arise in nature". People in symplectic geometry are exited by polyfolds: They can have components of varying dimensions and you can do analysis on polyfolds (but seems very complicated).

Comment: @ThomasRot can polyfolds be smooth or have differential structures